# lambda: capture `this` with a deleted assignment operator emits compiler warning

Tags: visual-c++, lambda, c++14, c++17, compiler-warnings

I have my project set to treat compiler warnings as errors and this seemingly trivial lambda capture is proving to be a head scratcher of an issue for me:

```
#pragma warning(default : 4626)
struct B{
  B& operator=(const B&) = delete;
  void f(){
    auto l = [this](){ // <== compiler warning
      /*body*/
    };
  }
};

int main(){
  return 0;
}
```

The code above produces the following warning in MSVC 2019 (16.2.5):

> warning C4626:  'B::f::<lambda_1>': assignment operator was implicitly defined as deleted

The warning is emitted for the lambda that captures `this` (and if I don't capture the `this` it compiles with no warnings).

Could someone explain to me the reason for the warning and if there's a way to write the code such that it compiles cleanly?

I understand that lambdas' assignment operators are implicitly deleted but not sure how (if) is that relevant to the warning I'm getting.

Comment: Cannot reproduce on godbolt using MSVC 19.14+ with your example. Are you sure that this minimal example trigger the error? If yes, which version of MSVC are you using?

Comment: You are right, I also had a line `#pragma warning(default : 4626)`

Comment: still can't repo

Answer (score 0):

iam in a similar situation and reproduced the warning like this:

```
#pragma warning(default : 4626)

struct A
{
  A& operator=(const A&) = delete;
};

struct B : public A
{
  //B& operator=(const B&) = delete;
  void f(){
    auto l = [](){ // <== compiler warning
      /*body*/
    };
  }
};

int main(){
  return 0;
}
```

Compiled with  `/std:c++latest /W4`
in my case it makes no difference if you capture this or not.

Is you class Inheriting from another class with a deleted operator= ?
I avoid that warning by explicitly deleting the operator= in my case.
This warning occured in MVS 19 16.3.0 compiling with /latest. with /std:c++17 there is no such warning.

**EDIT**

this warning also happens as soon something captured in the lamdba is used (captured by copy or ref doesnt matter):

```
#pragma warning(default : 4626)

int main()
{
    int foo;
    auto bar = [&]() {
        foo;
    };

  return 0;
}

<source>(8): warning C4626: 'main::<lambda_1>': assignment operator was implicitly defined as deleted
```

(with /std:c++latest /W4)